# Insert mysql query results into database column with corrensponding ids

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-5.7, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to store some data from a temporary query into a table, but it doesn't work.

Suppose we have the following data

Table_A

| Submission_id | Salesman | Customer name | Hobby | Carline | Fuel | Marketing_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | salesman1 | customer1 | hobby1 | car1,car2 | Fuel1 | hobby1,car1,car2,Fuel1 |
| 2 | salesman2 | customer2 | hobby1,hobby2 | car1 | Fuel2 | hobby1,hobby2,car1,Fuel2 |

And the radio Button/checkbox value table:
Table_B

| option_value | option_name |
| --- | --- |
| hobby1 | Football |
| hobby2 | Golf |
| car1 | SUV |
| car2 | Cabrio |
| Fuel1 | Gas |
| Fuel2 | Hybrid |

I've written the following code trying to match the options stored in the previous table against the column "Marketing_data" to obtain a new column:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c0.option_name)Marketing_data
FROM Table_A d
JOIN Table_B c0 ON FIND_IN_SET(c0.option_value, d.Marketing_data)
GROUP BY d.Marketing_data;
```

And the resulting column is composed as follow:

| Marketing_data |
| --- |
| Football, SUV, Cabrio, Gas |
| Football, Golf, SUV, Hybrid |

Now, what I'm trying to do is to insert the last column into the first table (Table_A). I tried with INSERT INTO command and I've also tried to generate another table containing the Submission_id field, but nothing worked. Have you got any suggestions? Many Thanks to everyone who will try to help me.

Answer (score 1):

It ais not a good ides to have a comma separated column in your database see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

But you can make following

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table_A
>     (`Submission_id` int, `Salesman` varchar(9), `Customer name` varchar(9), `Hobby` varchar(13), `Carline` varchar(9), `Fuel` varchar(5), `Marketing_data` varchar(24))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Table_A
>     (`Submission_id`, `Salesman`, `Customer name`, `Hobby`, `Carline`, `Fuel`, `Marketing_data`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'salesman1', 'customer1', 'hobby1', 'car1,car2', 'Fuel1', 'hobby1,car1,car2,Fuel1'),
>     (2, 'salesman2', 'customer2', 'hobby1,hobby2', 'car1', 'Fuel2', 'hobby1,hobby2,car1,Fuel2')
> ;
> ```

> 

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table_B
>     (`option_value` varchar(6), `option_name` varchar(8))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Table_B
>     (`option_value`, `option_name`)
> VALUES
>     ('hobby1', 'Football'),
>     ('hobby2', 'Golf'),
>     ('car1', 'SUV'),
>     ('car2', 'Cabrio'),
>     ('Fuel1', 'Gas'),
>     ('Fuel2', 'Hybrid')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE 
> Table_A a
> SET `Marketing_data` = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c0.option_name)Marketing_data
> FROM (SELECT * FROM Table_A) d
> JOIN Table_B c0 ON FIND_IN_SET(c0.option_value, d.Marketing_data)
>  WHERE a.`Submission_id` = d.`Submission_id`
>  GROUP BY d.Marketing_data)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Table_A;
> ```
>
> ```
> Submission_id | Salesman  | Customer name | Hobby         | Carline   | Fuel  | Marketing_data          
> ------------: | :-------- | :------------ | :------------ | :-------- | :---- | :-----------------------
>             1 | salesman1 | customer1     | hobby1        | car1,car2 | Fuel1 | Cabrio,Football,Gas,SUV 
>             2 | salesman2 | customer2     | hobby1,hobby2 | car1      | Fuel2 | Football,Golf,Hybrid,SUV
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=538f813e833f7b284deb0fa1354997ee)*

Comment: Hi, I tried to use the script in my SQL database, but the result is the following: #3105 - The value specified for generated column 'datimarketing' in table '1459630_form_1' is not allowed.

Comment: And this is the query that I've done: UPDATE 
1459630_form_1 a
SET 'datimarketing' = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c0.option_name)datimarketing
FROM (SELECT * FROM 1459630_form_1) d
JOIN 1459630_field_options c0 ON FIND_IN_SET(c0.option_value, d.datimarketing)
 WHERE a.`submission_id` = d.`submission_id`
 GROUP BY d.datimarketing)
 SELECT * FROM 1459630_form_1;

Comment: @FrancescoMarcucci Please amke your own dbfiddel to show your problem, comments are not the right place for it